# Telugu proverb equivalent in English

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, proverb-requests

There is a proverb in Telugu language which is as below.

**అన్నం లేకపోయినా, పట్టుబట్ట కడతా అన్నాడట**

It translates to someone who doesn't have a morsel to eat but insists on wearing expensive clothes. In short, a person who likes to show off but is disproportionate to his means.

What is the English equivalent proverb or idiom which conveys a similar meaning?

Comment: One common expression in this general area is [**keep up appearances**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appearance) *(maintain an impression of wealth or well-being)*. It's usually used in contexts where someone barely has the resources to maintain a show of wealth / health / whatever, but is highly motivated to conceal their *real* circumstances for some reason (often, just *personal pride*).

Comment: A proverb usually gives advice; it is not usually a nominal. Is 'proverb' accurate here, or is the translation loose? // @FF Also 'keep[ing] up with the Joneses'.

Comment: A related quotation by Anne Bradstreet : "He that hath nothing to feed on but vanity and lies must needs lie down in the bed of sorrow."

Comment: *Never judge a sausage by its skin*, and *Never judge a book by its cover* both warn against accepting outward appearances as a representation of the contents within. One effect of a poor person wearing expensive clothes is to give a false appearance of riches.

Answer (score 2):

Two idioms in Br English might fit the bill - particularly this one: "A three-bob millionaire" is someone who acts like they have a lot of money while only having a small amount ( three bob = three shillings in pre-decimal British currency); also one of the meanings of the expression 'fur coat and no knickers' is similar - ie someone (usually female) who dresses like a rich person whilst not having the means to buy underwear)

Answer (score 1):

One which covers much the same ground is

[You should] **Cut your coat according to your cloth.**

> This proverb advises a person to cut and stitch the coat according to
>   the cloth available; it warns that the size of the coat should not
>   exceed the piece of the cloth in hand. Otherwise, the coat will be unfit
>   to wear.... It is necessary for everyone to
>   make a proper plan before they begin to put any task into practice. A
>   person who spends more than their [disposable] income will soon fall
>   into trouble. They will have to face financial problems and hardships
>   and thereby mental agony. So this proverb instructs us to live within
>   our means and resources.... Harmony and proportion are very much [more
>   important than] [overall] income and expenditure.
>
> Some people are showy in life in order to make others think that they
>   are sophisticated and rich. Seeing others being rich and great, one
>   should not [strive to imitate] them. One must build a castle on the
>   ground –  not in the air –  with a strong foundation.... If one does
>   something without [recognising] their limitations they will soon be
>   sorry. If a person spends more than their income, they will some
>   [encounter serious problems]. So this proverb says that we should
>   spend money [wisely,] according to our income and resources.

[[English for Students; **much** tidied](http://www.english-for-students.com/cut-your-coat-according-to-your-cloth.html)]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact match, but "a donkey (or an ass) in lion's skin" refers to one of Aesop's fables.  A donkey used a lion's skin to make himself look more powerful and impressive than he really was.